# Python code not listing correct outputs. No errors showing

Tags: python

I am creating a screening process to find eligible stocks for a uni project I am doing but when I run this code I get this output instead of a list of stocks:

runcell(0, 'C:/Users/cades/Downloads/untitled3.py')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ticker, earnings_to_equity, debt_to_equity, quick_ratio]
Index: []

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd


tickers = yf.Tickers('')


financial_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ticker', 'earnings_to_equity', 'debt_to_equity', 'quick_ratio'])


for ticker in tickers.tickers:
        balance_sheet = ticker.balance_sheet
        income_statement = ticker.income_statement
        
        earnings_to_equity = income_statement.loc['Net Income'] / balance_sheet.loc['Total Stockholder Equity']
        debt_to_equity = balance_sheet.loc['Total Debt'] / balance_sheet.loc['Total Stockholder Equity']
        quick_ratio = (balance_sheet.loc['Total Current Assets'] - balance_sheet.loc['Inventory']) / balance_sheet.loc['Total Current Liabilities']

        
        if debt_to_equity < 2 and quick_ratio >= 1.5 and earnings_to_equity > 0:
            financial_data = financial_data.append({'ticker': ticker.ticker, 'earnings_to_equity': earnings_to_equity, 'debt_to_equity': debt_to_equity, 'quick_ratio': quick_ratio}, ignore_index=True)
            
        
        if len(financial_data) >= 100:
            break



print(financial_data)
```

Comment: `except:
        pass` is suppressing the errors, remove it and rerun the code. In general you should use `except SpecificException` to avoid catching everything

Comment: Thank you. I am now getting this error: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Did you only get rid of `pass`?  If so, get rid of the try/except as well

Comment: I have now gotten rid of the try/except as well but now when printing the financial data this is printed instead: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ticker, earnings_to_equity, debt_to_equity, quick_ratio]
Index: []

Comment: That's the error. To solve that, debug why you're getting an empty Pandas data frame.

Comment: Correction: you're getting an empty col in the Pandas data frame. you need to check that before running the reading line for those columns

Comment: Thank you. I am quite new to python, so would you be able to tell me how to do that.

Comment: Hi, Cade, welcome to Stack Overflow. A good place to start is 'how to ask a proper question' doc in SO site. You did it pretty good.
However, googling and checking the docs for every particular error is the route.
Asking help in every step is not gonna help you ;)
Have a nice day.

Comment: Dear Cade, please include the full error message in your question as an edit, format it in the same way as code is formatted (monospace font)

Answer (score 0):

*I'm gonna answer here the question asked, given that's gonna help future devs that come looking the same thing. Credits to @Caridorc for the catch; I'll go deep in **why you shouldn't do except pass**.*

try/except expressions catch the errors you get in the code happening between them, returning an object Exception if some exception happened.

In your code, after running the try, the except is catching the exception, however, instead of doing something with it, to correct or handle the error, you're just passing. Not even showing the msg. That's pretty much the programming equivalent to put the dirt under the rug. You must avoid that, even in 'just for now code' because you'll only mess with your future self: the debugger guy.

Instead of that, depending on how clean you want your code (try to do it cleaner, but if you're trying somenthing you may wanna save some time and that's OK), you can try this ways:

- to see a python traceback, totally rough, that does not handle anything, but let's you see the errors do this:

```
try:
    my_code()
except Exception as e: # in here you catch whereever exception happens
    raise e # then you don pass, you re raise it, so you can see what's happening
```

- Once you recognize the error (Pandas column empty in your case, you catch it, like this. To allow you do different things depending on error types. E.g: if pandas error, handle pandas error, if api error, handle api error and so on. You can group them by type, see python exceptions docs to know how.

```
try:
    my_code()
except (APIError, EmptyDataFrameColumns) as e: # in here you catch these two types
    code_that_handles_data_errors() #then you code what you need in those 2 cases
except Exception as e: # in here you catch the other exceptions
    raise e # then you re raise it, so you can see what's happening when you get a new exception you didn't know.
```

- You can also log the msg from the error object returned by python:

```
try:
    my_code()
except (APIError, EmptyDataFrameColumns) as e: # in here you catch these two types
    log.warning(f"Something went wrong with the external data. Here is the error: {e.messsage}")
    code_that_handles_data_errors() #then you code what you need in those 2 cases
except Exception as e: # in here you catch the other exceptions
    log.error(f"Something weird happened. Here is the error: {e.messsage}")
    #you only log here, bc you don't know the error, but you need to see it to be able to handle it for the future, reading the logs.
```

When I started, I usually looped between those status. **Never** except pass. And ***whenever possible, classify and handle the known errors***.